# "Value is Required" on arcpy.CalculateField

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm pretty new to Python, and am trying to write a script for use in ArcGIS 10.1 (arcpy); the basic idea is to add a new field (francis), check the values in several other fields, if any are null (-99) then output 0 into Francis, otherwise run a simple computation.However, I'm getting this error and am having trouble moving beyond it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\gislab2\Python\take_home\part1\prelim_if2.py", line 28, in   arcpy.CalculateField_management(Output_Feature_Class, "Francis", "", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
>
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3128, in CalculateField raise e
>
> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000735: Expression: Value is required Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Here's the code

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

print "start your engines"
# Script arguments
Shapefile = "C:\\gislab2\\Python\\take_home\\USCancer2000.shp"

Field_Name = Francis

Output_Feature_Class = "C:\\gislab2\\Python\\take_home\\USCancer2000.shp"

# Local variables:
USCancer2000__2_ = Output_Feature_Class

# Process: Add Field
arcpy.AddField_management(Shapefile, "Francis", "LONG", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Output_Feature_Class, "Francis", "", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
##
### Process: If-then check for missing values
##
if "Cnt1"==-99:
    Field_name=7
elif "Cnt2"==-99:
    Field_name=7
elif "Cnt3"==-99:
    Field_name=7
elif "Pop1"==-99:
    Field_name==7
elif "Pop2"==-99:
    Field_name=7
elif "Pop3"==-99:
    Field_name=7
else:
        Field_name=("Cnt1"+"Cnt2"+"Cnt3")/("Pop1"+"Pop2"+"Pop3")
print "done"
```

Many thanks in advance!
david

Comment: can you show the stack trace

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gislab2\Python\take_home\part1\prelim_if2.py", line 28, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(Output_Feature_Class, "Francis", "", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3128, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Expression: Value is required
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

>>>  thanks in advance

Comment: Put that in your question where it can be formatted properly and people can read it!

Comment: Just put it in the question, but the formatting still looks wonky, even when I try to indicate it as a code block

Comment: I tried to fix your traceback formatting—but your pasted source already had all whitespace collapsed, so I had to do a lot of guessing. You need to copy with the original newlines.

Comment: many thanks that looks better than the original!

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter in `arcpy.CalculateField_management` is telling it what to calculate. You're not passing anything there. As a test, replace that line with
`arcpy.CalculateField_management(Output_Feature_Class, "Francis", 5, "PYTHON_9.3", "")` and see if it evaluates.

Once it successfully runs, then you should look into using an expression and codeblock to do the calculations you want. See the Calculate Ranges (third) example [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000).

**--Alternative--**

You also may find it easier to use the [updateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000). It seems like more work than using calculateField, but it can be a lot faster and saves you the trouble of writing out a convoluted codeblock.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

print "start your engines"
# Script arguments
Shapefile = "C:\\gislab2\\Python\\take_home\\USCancer2000.shp"

Field_Name = "Francis"

# Process: Add Field
arcpy.AddField_management(Shapefile, "Francis", "LONG", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

fields = ["Cnt1", "Cnt2", "Cnt3", "Pop1", "Pop2", "Pop3", "Francis"] # the fields you want available to you in the cursor

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefile, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: # step through each row
        if not -99 in row: # Check for nulls
            # none found, do the math
            row[6] = (row[0] + row[1] + row[2]) / (row[3] + row[4] + row[5])
        else:
            # nulls found, zero out the result
            row[6] = 0
        cursor.updateRow(row) # save it

print "done"
```